# Year variable repeating and producing mutiple iterations of itself on the graph

Tags: javascript

Im unable to find why my year variable keeps posting itself on the graph and then turns into a blurry word, I also have a problem where my graphs are not are spaced to be in touch with each other.

````
this.draw = function () {

    // Draw the title above the plot.
    this.drawTitle();

    // Draw x and y axis.
    drawAxis(this.layout);

    // Draw x and y axis labels.
    drawAxisLabels(this.xAxisLabel, this.yAxisLabel, this.layout);

    // Calculate the number of nutrients and years
    var numNutrients = this.data.getRowCount();
    var numYears = this.endYear - this.startYear + 1; // Add 1 to include the end year

    // Calculate the width and height of each bar dynamically
    var barWidth = (this.layout.plotWidth() - this.layout.pad * numYears) / (numNutrients * numYears);
    var barHeightMax = this.layout.plotHeight() / 100;

    for (var j = 0; j < numYears; j++) {
      var year = this.startYear + j;
      var x = this.mapYearToWidth(year) + j * (barWidth + this.layout.pad);

      for (var i = 0; i < numNutrients; i++) {
        var nutrientName = this.data.getString(i, 0);
        var value = this.dataByYear[j][i];

        var barHeight = this.mapPayGapToHeight(value, this.maxPercentage); // Scale the bar height based on the maximum value
        var y = this.layout.bottomMargin - barHeight;

        // Draw the bar
        fill(this.colors[i]);
        rect(x, y, barWidth, barHeight);

        // Display the year below the bar with the smaller font size
        fill(0);
        textAlign(CENTER);
        text(year, x + barWidth / 2, this.layout.bottomMargin + this.layout.pad + yearFontSize * 1.5); // Adjusted vertical position

        x += barWidth;
      }
    }
  };```
````